# How do I invoke a Java method which returns a list in JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp

I've looked into invoking a Java method but I am stuck trying to call a Java method which returns a list so that I can use that list in JSP.

JSP:

```
<%@ page import="mainPack.ShoppingService"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>

     $('#mainCheckbox').on( "change",function () {
            <%
             ShoppingService s = new ShoppingService();
            %>
            <%
            List<String> storesList = s.getStoresList();
            %>
            //unresolved variable error
            console.log(storesList.contains("Macys"));

        });
```

Java:

```
 public List<String> getStoresList() {
        return storeDao.getStoresList();
 }
```

---

I've also tried going into the controller and making it an attribute.

JSP:

```
 $('#mainCheckbox').on( "change",function () {
                //I get a Uncaught Reference Error: Macys Not Defined
                var jsArray = ${storesList};
    
            });
```

Java:

```
model.addAttribute("storesList", ShoppingService.getStoresList());
```

I am not sure the second attempt isn't working. When I open up debugger I see that it seems to translate the list into:

```
var jsArray = [Macys, JcPenny, Kohls, Target];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return / display list into JSP , then this is what I am thinking --

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<html>
<%List<String> str=new ArrayList(); 
str.add(0, "testing");
str.add(1, "testing1");
str.add(2, "testing2");
%>
<tr><%=str%></tr>


</html>
```